# How do I get the svnindex.cmd script included with SrcSrv to index source files with URI-escaped spaces in them?

Tags: svn, debugging, windbg, pdb-files, srcsrv

I recently set up a symbol server and added [SrcSrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support to our build scripts so that we can easily debug crash dumps from the field and have WinDbg and/or the Visual Studio debugger get the correct version of the source files from our Subversion repository that were used to compile whatever particular version of our application crashed.

I added a line to our build script to invoke the stock `svnindex.cmd` script that comes with the Debugging Tools for Windows package, but found out the script garbles repository filepaths that contain URI-escaped characters such as spaces, so WinDbg can't download the files from the repository.

Note that `svnindex.cmd` (specifically the `svn.pm` Perl script that it kicks off) gets repository locations for source files from the output of the `svn info` command, and `svn` URI-escapes repository paths. When `svnindex.cmd` encounters this, it mangles the path. For example, it will turn the path

```
"http://mysvnrepo/My%20Application/trunk/Database%20Layer/OracleAdapter.cs"
```

into

```
"http://mysvnrepo/My20Layer/OracleAdapter.cs"
```

It turns out that SrcSrv interprets anything between "%" as a variable name that it replaces at runtime.

Assuming that renaming all the directories in our repository to remove spaces and other "special" characters that would be URI-escaped is not feasible, how do I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to fix this issue is to edit the `svn.pm` Perl script that `svnindex.cmd` runs to embed source server metadata into your PDB files.

If you have WinDbg 6.11.0001.404, this file is located in the `srcsrv` directory under the Debugging Tools for Windows installation directory (for example, on my machine it's located in `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\srcsrv`). In older versions of WinDbg, this file is under `sdk\srcsrv`. In my case, I edited the copy of `svn.pm` on our build server, since the build server is what actually calls `svnindex.cmd`.

My solution was to simply unescape the URI-escaped file paths before they are processed further by the script. I added the following lines to the `GatherFileInformation` subroutine in `svn.pm`, after the `while` loop that starts with the comment `# Loop on "Path:" entries`. I added these lines after the closing brace for that loop (line 206 in my copy of `svn.pm`):

```
    # Fix for Subversion URL's. The "%" character is treated specially by SRCSRV, so
    # we need to remove URI escape sequeneces to get rid of them
    # - Mike Spross (3/30/2011)

    use URI::Escape;
    $FileRepository = uri_unescape($FileRepository);
    $FileRelative = uri_unescape($FileRelative);
```

This solved the problem and allowed me to pull full sources running WinDbg on my development machine.